# Android emulator not working when x86_64 system image on my MacBook pro M1

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, apple-m1

Android emulator works fine when CPU is arm64. However, react-native does not like arm64, and it is causing me performance issues.
Therefore, I need x86_64. However, when trying to run the emulator with x86_64 system image following message occurs:  The emulator process for AVD Pixel xl API 29 has terminated.
Why this is happening, and what is the solution? Thanks

Comment: wipe data of your emulator and try again, Try running minimal process at the same time. It will boost your process execution a bit for Emulator.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I deleted the emulator from the sdk tools, installed it back. and still the same issue

Comment: @Patrick89 Did you find any fix for this problem?